# ActionScript 3 add boss in the enemies array

Tags: actionscript

how can i make the boss hit same as enemy with this code

In enemies class I have

```
public var hit:int = 200;
```

and in engine class

```
enem[e].hit -= 50;
if(enem[e].hit <= 0)
{
   enem[e].removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enem[e].gogo);
   enem.splice(e, 1);
   e--;
}
```

How can I make the boss in the same array as here? In number of enemies hits, so the boss will minus number of hits in the same array as enemies. Will make it into the code over.

Comment: I have no idea what are you trying to do here. Can you please rephrase the question?

Comment: The boss can be working with same hit as enemies. so that I don't need make a if(boss.hit <= 0) for boss, I can make it in enemies Array. Working in if(enem[e].hit <= 0)

Comment: can't you add the boss as last element of the enem array?

Answer (score 0):

The **boss** class needs to also have the hit variable in it's scope, although it doesn't necessarily have to equal the same amount as the **enemies** class.

```
public var hit:int = 200;
```

As Nadia suggested, you can then add the **boss** instance to the **enem** array.  It may not necessarily need to be the last element though.